# display non-English characters in python response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, character-encoding, python-requests

I am a newbie of python and I am trying to get the content of a Chinese website, I could get the response `r` but unfortunately, it has an encoding/decoding problem. i.e the Chinese characters are not displayed correctly.

```
import requests
r =requests.get('http://www.example.com')
print (r.encoding)
print (r.content)
```

The code above would print the encoding as "ISO-8859-1"

The content of the response contains the information as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="gb2312"?>
```

I also saw something like this

```
<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312"/>
```

The Chinese characters are displayed as something like `\xbe\xc9\xbd\xf0\xc9\xbd`, which is supposed to be three Chinese characters. Could anybody advise what should I do to display the characters correctly?

I am trying to do this in Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know your exact encoding type but generally it's enough to use:

```
r.content.decode('gh2312')
```

or

```
r.content.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

as far as I know. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set the response's decoding directly.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://yourwebsite.com')
response.encoding = "gb2312"
txt = response.text
```

Nowadays, utf8 has become the most popular encoding for Chinese websites and requests response shall be set correctly by checking the encoding of the page. I summarize the solution in a post [Chinese Encoding with Python Requests Library](https://www.wwwinsights.com/python/python-requests-chinese-encoding/).